# Many Case Regex1 Extract Values, How Can I?

Tags: regex, splunk

I need some your help.

I using Regex1 about data extract.
However many cases how can I do that?

Example

```
hOme = 0.00
AbC= 0.50
KEN123 =0.80
4  =  1.00
5=200
```

Can you advice to me?

Just I extract using

```
hOme\s\=\s(?<Home>[\d\.]+) ....
```

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might be the desired output, yet this expression might be an option to start:

```
([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jfu3zq/1/)

Another option would be:

```
(?i)(home|abc|ken123|4|5)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RUOGGR/1/)

Or maybe:

```
(?i)(home)\s*=\s*(.*)|(abc)\s*=\s*(.*)|(ken123)\s*=\s*(.*)|(4)\s*=\s*(.*)|(5)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ueit0j/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Ueit0j/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But How Can I data extract. Example Home=0.00, ABC=0.50, KEN123=0.80... Thanks I'm Completed this problem.